# Removing content from Liferay database

Tags: sql-server-2012, liferay-6

**CONTEXT:** We are working on a portal project using **Liferay6.1** and **SQL Server 12** database. Every time a release happens to production, we refresh our Integration and Dev databases with production db. As the size of the Production database is very large, we would like to strip down the database (may be by removing content) and have a smaller sized database. 
Also We want developers to set their development environment on local systems which requires a smaller db.

**QUESTION**: How to strip down the liferay database without compromising on the portal functionalities? Any sugestions? feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Striping down the database will require more efforts, if you have lot of custom objects and they are tightly coupled with Liferay. Export/Import feature not available for custom object, you need to write Data Handler for them and if you have huge data, using lar to import/export data may not help. You need to consider all aspects before striping database as if you missed few references of data deleted from other tables, you will face different issues.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "strip down the liferay database", I believe you want only portal configuration like communities, WC, structure, Template, Org, etc. If that is the case, you can pretty much export the each of them via Control panel and import them on your local environment. If you need any other custom data, you can pretty much write your control panel screen to export/import them. This way you can control what you want to import in your environment. Otherwise, a selective DB table export/import is the option. The bottom line is it all comes to what you eventually need for your local/DEV envrionment to be up and running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually we have more custom tables linked to LR tables. So we are planning to start with clean LR instance and building on top of it only required ones.

Answer (score 0):

Webcontent are stored in JournalArticle table, but isn't recommended to do manual changes in the database. You can execute a Groovy script in the Control Panel to delete the oldest and expired web contents.

You can get the script from:

https://github.com/atrujillofalcon/liferay-clean-journal-history

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your portal schema / database and application schema / database. Then connect one of you non-production servers with both the databases. Follow the below steps

1. Create minimal portal configuration like sites, users. layouts and portlets. This will reduce the size of the portal data.
2. Export the portal schema / database.
3. Save the exported databases file and liferay-home\data\document_library directory as your baseline copy of the configuration.
4. You can update the baseline files as and when required.

Now to replicate you should import the portal schema \ database and place the document_library directory in liferay-home\data. Connect to the application schema \ databases and start the server.

The solution also demands a process orientation and I suggest you should craft a process around the solution.